# Matching null objects in regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match all objects in an array that have a property with value of `null`

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "None",
    grade: 'A'
  },
  {              <== match here
    id: 2,     
    name: null, 
    grade: 'C'
  },             <== to here
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "None",
    grade: 'B'
  },
]
```

I currently have the following regex statement that tries to match surrounding text between the , though it will not match when I insert 'null' in between the multiline match

`\{((.*\n.*)+null(.*\n.*)+)\}`

Is there an easier way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\{[^{]*null[^}]*\}
```

**Explanation**

- `\{` : We want the first opening bracket
- `[^{]*` : Assuming it is a flat object, we need every character to be not another opening bracket
- `null` : This is the magical text we're after
- `[^}]*` : We need the rest of the object, so look for all characters that aren't the closing bracket
- `\}` : match the closing bracket

---

I know this is not robust, but if your data is strictly formatted, this should do it.

After seeing your attempt, you might want to look into the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Comment: @Chris No problem, take a look at the link (and also the rest of the site), it's really great for regexes